# Why is the number of solutions to this problem finite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The problem is:

> Let $y-2x$ be a factor of $x-1$; $x$ is a power of $3$, and $y$ is a power of $2$.
> Prove that $x=3$ and $y=8$ is the only solution.

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve this? We will be able to provide more useful answers if you give us more context about where you got the question, where you got stuck, etc.

Comment: Does anyone know how to approach this at all? Logarithms don't seem to work and I don't know how else I could do it.

Comment: How do I bounty it

Comment: @FinlayHutchinson I think you need to have more reputation to bounty it.